# Get the row count of gzipped utf file

Tags: python

I have a Python script which does some operations on a gzipped utf file. I want to check if the file is an empty file before I process the file. I saw a few anwsers in SO which suggests to use this:

```
isize = U32(read32(self.fileobj))
```

But this doesn't work for 0kb utf files which I tested. Also this method has a constraint that it can be used only for files less than 4 gigs.

I did this and can get the row count of the file:

```
input_file = gzip.open(argv[0], 'rb')
row_count= len(list(input_file))
print "file rows size", row_count
if (row_count==0):
    print ('Input file has no records.')
    sys.exit(0)

input_file.seek(0)
```

But is this efficient since my input file will be of size > 70gigs.

**EDIT:** My requirement is to skip the processing if the file is a 0 kb file. But gzipping the UTF file makes it 1kb, so I cannot check that as well. Is there any other way around this ?

Also I want to skip the whole process , if the file has 
1. No rows
2. Empty rows ie. `\n`'s

Comment: if you have very huge file and still want to count the rows ..  you have to put the dumb loop over the `input_file` and do `count=count+1` easy logic ...

Comment: Added my requirement, pls check.

Comment: inshort your requirement is "skip the file if it have no lines!!" , same logic works for you bro ... check the count ... if its `zero`, skip the processing!!

Comment: The file can have many lines but can be 0kb.

Comment: i'm strongly disagree on this ...  its not atall possible that file can have lines  and its 0kb ... please explain how come file have data and OS is showing it as 0kb?

Comment: You misunderstood me. Suppose if there are few empty lines in a file. But the file size is 0kb. There are not characters in the file. Just a few \n's

Comment: I dunno if a file with just carriage returns will have a size or not. But in that case, I will have to process the file since the row count will be greater than 0

Comment: nops, if you have empty lines in your file i.e. few `\n` its comsider as data and your file size becomes more than 0kb, just tried on linux and windows both ...  you also try!!

Comment: ok. In that case, the file will not be skipped since it has lines but will not process since it does not have data. I want to skip the file if it is 0 kb, if it has empty lines, or if it has 0 lines. This is my requirement :D

Comment: ok, follow this steps and let me know howz it? take count first, while taking count do not increese it if its `\n`, finally check the count if its `zero` skip file processing else process file :)

Comment: @ViChU I think you should tell what processing you are about to do.

Comment: @AmeyJadiye Yes will try this out thanks :)

Comment: @skyking I will be splitting the file into individual files based on certain criteria. This process has a for loop in it.

Answer (score 2):

No it's not efficient unless your computer has 96GiB RAM or so. What you should do is to not put the lines in a list (which is what will use up much memory), preferably you should process the data in one go.

Your requirement was not clear form the start, but it seems like you don't have to count the lines after all. Just start processing the file, if it's empty you handle that when you find that out:

```
input_file = gzip.open(argv[0], "rb")

for l in input_file:
    process_line(l)
    row_count += 1

print "file rows size", row_count
# etc
```

Note that if the file does not contain any lines the loop will terminate immediately and you will pass through to the print statement. The same is true if you have a lot of empty lines that you should skip, just skip them.

You should aim at reading the file just once since you otherwise have to (since you probably don't have 96GiB of RAM) either unpack the file twice or you have to store the unpacked data in a temporary file (if you try to put it in a list, that will only end up in your swap file and that will not be any better).

To analyze the difference we can first consider the construct:

```
row_count = len([l for l in input_file if condition(x)])
```

and compare with

```
row_count = 0
for l in input_file:
    if condition(l):
        row_count += 1
```

both constructs has to read `input_file` to extract all lines and evaluate the python expression `condition(x)`, that much is the same. In both there's counting and looping involved which in the first case is done more in C than in the second which might lead someone to think that the former is faster. The major difference comes from the first is storing a list of the lines in RAM and when RAM runs out the data will instead hit the swap file and it's unlikely that the small amount of time saved by using more C will outweight this (even the fact that you actually create a list may be enough to offset this advantage).

Now as we seen that both techniques do read the entire `input_file` to determine if there's lines to be processed, and this can't likely be avoided (especially with the condition involved). Now for the first check the number of lines and then process the file compared to the just-go-ahead-and-process approach:

```
row_count = 0
for l in input_file:
    if condition(l):
        row_count += 1

input_file.seek(0)
if row_count > 0:
    for l in input_file:
        if condition(l):
            process_line(l)
```

compared with

```
row_count = 0
for l in input_file:
    if condition(l):
        process_line(l)
        row_count += 1
```

Let's consider the cases where there's no rows to be processed you will in both cases loop through the file and evaluate `condition(l)` (that will evaluate to `False`). And then you're finished. No major difference there (actually there is a slight difference since in the second case you don't have to check the value of `row_count` to see if you're done).

In the case that there is rows to be processed then the second loop in the first approach and the loop in the second is almost the same (if you don't need the `row_count` for anything else they could be exactly the same). The difference is that the first loop would have to be run first.

Basically to count the lines before you decide to process the data is just a waste of time. There's no way you can count the number of lines without actually reading the file and counting them.

Comment: I have another for loop for processing the rows. So adding this will double my processing time.

Comment: @ViChU if the file has no line count, the for loop will be skipped! Try it!

Comment: @skyking This is the approach I have used already. I wanted to check the line count so that I can skip processing the line part. And also, using this approach will process the empty lines too, which is the actual aim of my question.

Comment: @skyking I thought of using the row count so that I can skip the whole process.

Comment: @ViChU What do you think you should be able to gain by that? Unless you've kept something important from us there's nothing.  The point is that you're counting the lines that is to be processed and once you found a line to count then you've got a line to process too (at that point you can conclude that you should process the input and can do so right away).